# Python deserialize kafka message with avro repository

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, avro

I need to read Kafka messages using an avro stored in the repository.
Using kafka-python 2.0.2, I can connect to the Kafka topic and read the messages but I have no idea on how to decode them.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer('SOME-TOPIC', 
                        other connection parameters,
                        auto_offset_reset= 'earliest')
                        # value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')))
                        # value_deserializer=lambda m: decode(m))

for msg in consumer:
    print (msg)
```

What library should I use ? confluent-kafka 1.5.0, avro-python3 1.10.1
How to proceed ?

- Identify the version of the message
- Connect to the avro repository
- Get the avro with the right version
- Use it to decode the message

That seems a lot to do, is there not a simpler way to do ?
I would appreciate to get an example to guide me.

To connect to the avro repository I have these parameters

- basic.auth.credentials.source
- schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info
- schema.registry.url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working with the following libraries:

```
pip install confluent-avro
pip install kafka-python
```

And the code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

from confluent_avro import AvroKeyValueSerde, SchemaRegistry
from confluent_avro.schema_registry import HTTPBasicAuth

KAFKA_TOPIC = "SOME-TOPIC"

registry_client = SchemaRegistry(
    "https://...",
    HTTPBasicAuth("USER", "PASSWORD"),
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json"},
)
avroSerde = AvroKeyValueSerde(registry_client, KAFKA_TOPIC)

consumer = KafkaConsumer(KAFKA_TOPIC, 
                        other connection parameters,
                        auto_offset_reset= 'earliest')

for msg in consumer:
    v = avroSerde.value.deserialize(msg.value)
    k = avroSerde.key.deserialize(msg.key)
    print(msg.offset, msg.partition, k, v)
    break
```

Reference: https://pypi.org/project/confluent_avro/